# Java array reading loop never ends?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Hi I am new to programming and today i was writing a code for one Java array task and in the beginning i tried just to test what i have done and in the first for loop (the array reading ) the program does not stop to read a numbers even i already enter a number (n) for its length. Please help ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ReadTwoElementsForArrayAndSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter N element:");
        int n = in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Please enter K element, for k < N: ");
        int k = in.nextInt();

        int[] arrayN = new int[n];
        System.out.print("Please enter N numbers for the array:  ");

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayN.length; i++) {
            arrayN[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        boolean changed = false;
        do {
            int temp = 0;           
            for( int i = 0; i < (arrayN.length-1); i++) {
                if(arrayN[i] > arrayN[i+1]){
                    temp = arrayN[i];
                    arrayN[i] = arrayN[i+1];
                    arrayN[i+1] = temp;
                    changed = true;

                }
            }
         } while (changed);
         for(int i = 0; i < arrayN.length; i ++) {
            System.out.printf("%d", arrayN[i]);
            System.out.print(k);
        }


        in.close();


    }

}
```

Comment: yep does the control ever go to this line `changed = true;` if it does while(true) will cause do-while to run for-ever

Comment: If you are trying to sort the array, you could just use `Arrays.sort(arrayN);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop is infinite because once the if condition inside for loop is executed then `changed` is set to `true` and its value never changed to false causing infinite loop by do while loop.

Instead you can use `Arrays.sort(arrayN)` or if you want to use loop only then try below code

```
 int count = 0;
 do {
    int temp = 0;
    count++;
    for (int i = 0; i < (arrayN.length - 1); i++) {
        if (arrayN[i] > arrayN[i + 1]) {
            temp = arrayN[i];
            arrayN[i] = arrayN[i + 1];
            arrayN[i + 1] = temp;


        }
    }
 } while (count < (arrayN.length));
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/XqwX2a)

Comment: thank you but i did't get why my previous for cycle is crushing because of the do while :(

Comment: @Yordan because you only changed the value of `changed` value to `true` and not to false anywhere and the do while is executed infinite times because its condition is true not false

Answer (score 0):

in this loop :

```
    do {
        int temp = 0;           
        for( int i = 0; i < (arrayN.length-1); i++) {
            if(arrayN[i] > arrayN[i+1]){
                temp = arrayN[i];
                arrayN[i] = arrayN[i+1];
                arrayN[i+1] = temp;
                changed = true;

            }
        }
     } while (changed);
```

you once change the `changed` to `true` and never make it `false`. If you want to end your loop you must some how(it depends on your approach) make `changed` false so it can end the loop.

Answer (score 0):

what you should be doing in a do-while loop is

```
boolean flag=true;
do{
     (some condition){
         flag=false;
     }

}while(flag)
```

this causes correct execution of do-while loop